# Reactflow lock graph

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

Is it possible to make reactflow graph locked ? something like isLocked=true

I would like to get the easiest way to implement this. Just wanna get graph with 'view only' mode, for representing ready graphs from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ReactFlow
          nodes={nodes}
          edges={edges}
          ref={flowRef}
          onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
          onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
          onConnect={onConnect}
          onInit={setReactFlowInstance}
          onDrop={onDrop}
          defaultViewport={defaultViewport}
          nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
          onDragOver={onDragOver}
          onNodeDragStop={handleDragEnd}
          onNodeDoubleClick={handleNodeDoubleClick}
          fitView
          multiSelectionKeyCode="Shift"
          edgesUpdatable={!isLocked}
          edgesFocusable={!isLocked}
          nodesDraggable={!isLocked}
          nodesConnectable={!isLocked}
          nodesFocusable={!isLocked}
          elementsSelectable={!isLocked}
        ></ReactFlow>
```